# API Newbie - PHP Curl Call

Tags: php

I am new to API's so please be easy on me! My school has a ooen data platform API for anyone to use. So, I decided to get a user & key in order to test stuff out. The following code snippet is my script in order to print out the details of a course.

```
<?php
$APIUSER = “***”; //user value from your application 
$APIKEY = “***”; //Api key value from your application 
$url = "https://opendata.concordia.ca/API/v1/course/description/filter/000106";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL =>   $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>    true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING =>    "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS =>    10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>    30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION =>   CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST =>    "GET",
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST =>    0,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER =>    0,
  CURLOPT_HEADER =>    0,
  CURLOPT_USERPWD =>    $APIUSER . ":" . $APIKEY
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
print($response);

?>
```

I tested my API user & API key on the `$url` page and it worked. Unfortunately, when I run the script on a local server, there is nothing printing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try making it a POST request instead of GET? Try changing `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST"`

Comment: Returns the following: `HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.`

Comment: Found the documentation for that API https://opendataconcordiau.github.io/documentation/ (looks identical to your example). Trying changing back to GET and using `var_dump($response)` instead of print

Comment: The page responds `string(0) ""`

Comment: Last thing to try: lets see if there are any error messages we aren't seeing. Add this after the curl_exec

```if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}```

and add to the opts
`CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1`